# How to copy a array consisting of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, syntax, copy

I have this array of vectors, vectors of pair:
`vector<pair<int, int> > adj[V];`

How can i copy this to another variable ?

```
vector<pair<int, int> > adjCopy[V] = adj; //not working;
```

I also tried using `std:copy` but is shows that vector(variable size) is inside the array so, cannot copy.

Comment: what is `V`? It can't be other than a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<pair<int, int> > adjCopy[V];
std::copy_n(&adj[0], V, &adjCopy[0]); // or std::copy(&adj[0], &adj[0] + V, &adjCopy[0]);
```

More idiomatic:

```
vector<pair<int, int> > adjCopy[V];
std::copy_n(begin(adj), V, begin(adjCopy)); // or std::copy(begin(adj), end(adj), begin(adjCopy));
```

---

In general, don't use C-arrays, use `std::array`,

```
std::array<std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >, V> adj;
auto adjCopy = adj;
```